# error when apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

I followed google documentation to integrate my app to Google Analytics.
But when adding

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and building my app, I encountered this error:

```
Error:(49, 0) For input string: "+"
```

These are the settings I used in the build.gradle of my application:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.xyz"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            manifestApplicationId : "${applicationId}",
            onesignal_app_id : "ccd48c54-2069-41f9-8ff7-54c7a12f2d18a",
            onesignal_google_project_number: "306632981237"
        ]
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

These are the setting in build.gradle application:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: post your gradle full trace.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At first you should call

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha2'
}
```

**Don't** (Avoid calling `+`)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
```

Do

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 17):

Need to enter the following entry in both gradle:

1. Add the following to the @project level gradle file:

   ```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
   ```
2. Add the following to the @app level gradle file:

   ```
   // Dependency for Google Sign-In
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
   ```
3. Add plugin:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

Comment: I'm working with ionic/cordova. Can you explain what is meant about project level and app level my build.gradle is at myApp/platforms/android/build.gradle. But there is also build.gradle at myApp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to the @project level gradle file:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'`

with the following 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'`

in the application build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

As many ppl said, I've added "**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'**" in the project level gradle.

But, I encountered another error saying **"File google-services.json is missing from module root folder."**. 
Eventually, I needed to set up a project via the following link. https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android

After setting up a project and it took me to go to Firebase console. In that page, I was able to download **google-service.json** file which was essential to solve this issue.

Drag and drop that JSON file under your project's '/app' folder.

It took me an hour to figure it out.
I hope it's helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

"Please take note that the classpath has been updated. The new classpath entry is 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'[image]

Comment: Upvoted, since this was helpful to me. It would be even more helpful with copyable text and a link to the info.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact issue, and the following fixed it.. go to platforms>android>project.properties and edit the lines

```
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+
```

to

```
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.1
```

It is said that `# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!`
But this fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Change following code in `project.properties` from:

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
```

to

```
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1
```

and add `google-service.json` file to app module

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you have to update your ***REALM-PLUGIN*** and you need to write this in ***Top-Level Gradle (Project:Gradle)***, copy paste below "***classpath***" line:

```
buildscript {
  ... 
  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0' //<--Your answer.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put line apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' twice in line 0 and line 49 simply remove one line

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29844477)