# Gradle Sync and Build Fail

Tags: android

Getting an error in gradle sync and build. The error is coming when i try to add firebase core sdk , else the app successfully build and runs , its just the firebase core sdk that is causing an sync failure when i try and adding it.

I Have Tried using every solution on the internet but nothing seems to be working, also tried the solution that the error provide the one with adding tools to the manifest but that doesn't work either
Error is:

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Build.gradle(Project)

```
  {
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

    }
```

Build.Gradle(Module:app)

```
{

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "ca.mohawk.patel.capstoneproject"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest merger failed after adding Firebase core version 17.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839238/manifest-merger-failed-after-adding-firebase-core-version-17-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

```
Build.gardle(Module:app){

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ca.mohawk.patel.capstoneproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}

}
```

//
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' - This statement should be at the end of the all line of code.

Comment: This link will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311880/error-when-apply-plugin-com-google-gms-google-services

Answer (score 0):

from [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019)

> This release is a MAJOR version update and includes breaking changes.
>   With this release, libraries are migrated from the Android Support
>   Libraries to the Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries.

The updated libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- **Upgrade** com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
- **Upgrade** compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
- **Update** your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX.

from gradle file, you are using `android support library` please change to [`androidx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx/55849025#55849025)