# > Could not find method apply() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

[image: this was the error][image: This is the code Build file 'C:\Users\ANAM\AndroidStudioProjects\employeedetails\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25]

I tried upgrading the gradle plugin, also tried deleting the gradle folder. But the error is in line:25 in app level build.gradle file.

```
'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

according to error, showing there.
Hoping for early reply as possible

Comment: Check this question's answers; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311880/error-when-apply-plugin-com-google-gms-google-services

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you wrote

```
apply 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

instead of

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```